# Make ColdFusion on Ubuntu case-insensitive

Tags: apache, ubuntu, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, case-sensitive

I've installed apache2 and ColdFusion 9 on an Ubuntu 12.04 box. I've already use the CheckSpelling mod in Apache to disable case-sensitive URLs and other paths that Apache is responsible for.

Now, keep in mind, I'm working with about 4GB of legacy code (about 6 years worth) and very little is up to convention. The coders before me were not concerned with case sensitivity, seeing as how the application was hosted on a Windows Box. For the most part, ColdFusion is behaving with `<cfinclude>` and `CreateObject`, but it seems like `<cfinvoke>` (which is used quite often in the codebase) is still case sensitive.

Now, I've tried the method of moving the code onto a vfat partition, but what I ran into was a whole bunch of encoding issues with filenames (we deal with foreign companies and get a lot of special characters). Deleting and/or renaming the files would be cumbersome, as most are also referred to in the MySQL database, and would have to be modified there as well. So recoding is somewhat of a nightmare.

So, I'm curious if ColdFusion has any special flags when running on Linux to be case insensitive, or if there is another method for making this all come together?

**EDIT**

I'm Sorry, I was mistaken. `cfinvoke` seems to work ok. I'm choking on `cfobject`

Comment: From the CF9 docs for CFINVOKE: 
"On UNIX systems, ColdFusion searches first for a file with a name that matches the specified component name, but is all lower case. If it does not find the file, it looks for a file name that matches the component name exactly, with the identical character casing."
So basically the filename shouldn't be bombing.  Can you share what exactly the error is?  It may be that the pathing is the problem.

Comment: @Sharondio I'm sorry, I was mistaken. they are `cfobject` statments

Comment: Per the docs, the same file search process applies to CFOBJECT.  So based on that, I'd try leaving the code alone and changing the case of all the components to lower-case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some research, and this is what I came up with...

[Creating Custom Tags (help.adobe.com)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0b2e1-7fff.html)

> Note: **Although tag names in ColdFusion pages are not case sensitive**, custom tag filenames must be lowercase on UNIX.

[cfinvoke Documentation (help.adobe.com)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e0a.html)

> On UNIX systems, ColdFusion searches first for a file with a name **that matches the specified component name, but is all lower case.** If it does not find the file, it looks for a file name that matches the component name exactly, with the identical character casing.

Since `<cfinvoke>` is a standard tag, the tag itself is case-insensitive. However, it sounds like all component argument(s) to `<cfinvoke>` need to have a lower-case filenames in order for calls with irregular casing to succeed consistently. I know you said refactoring is difficult, but this is what I've come up with:

If you have a folder where you specifically keep components, it's trivial to run a shell script in that folder that renames them all to have lower-casing (remove -i if you don't want to be asked if you're sure each time):

```
for filename in *.cfc; do
  lowercase =`echo $filename | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
  mv -i $filename $lowercase
done
```

If you don't have the components all in the same folder, try it from the top directory.

Let me know if you were able to give this a shot!

Comment: +1 for a reasonable answer. I'll probably end up accepting as well. However, my manager won't allow me to change all filenames to lower case as he finds it easier to read them in CamelCase. >:-( I'm leaving it open in case anyone can come up with something that just makes ColdFusion match any case, but will accept if nothing comes up

Comment: Talked the boss into it. Worked beautifully